# Airflow DAG failing with No Active Warehouse Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow

Airflow DAG is failing with 'No Active Warehouse'.

I'm using the get variable method and getting all connection, role and database details.

The DAG is working fine if I call database, role, schema details directly instead of getting from variables.

Below is the Dag Snippet:

```
from airflow.contrib.hooks.snowflake_hook import SnowflakeHook
from airflow.providers.snowflake.operators.snowflake import SnowflakeOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.sensors.external_task_sensor import ExternalTaskSensor
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pymsteams
import logging

load_mstr_str = f"call SP_OD_CTL_ETL_EXEC();"

default_args = {
    'owner': 'MT',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2015, 6, 1),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email': ['notify@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'on_failure_callback': send_failure_msg,
    'retries': 0
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id=DAG_ID,
    catchup=False,
    default_args=default_args,
    description="Execute Stored Procs for tables",
    schedule_interval="30 11 * * *"
)


load_mstr_sp = SnowflakeOperator(
    task_id='load_mstr_sp',
    dag=dag,
    snowflake_conn_id=Variable.get("SNOWFLAKE_CONN_ID"),
    sql=load_mstr_str,
    warehouse=Variable.get("SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE"),
    database=Variable.get("SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE"),
    schema=Variable.get("SNOWFLAKE_SCHEMA"),
    role=Variable.get("SNOWFLAKE_ROLE"),
    on_failure_callback=send_failure_msg,
)
```

Failing with Below error:

```
snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 000606 (57P03): 01ab6bc6-0502-c477-0030-c80359694e8a: No active warehouse selected in the current session.  Select an active warehouse with the 'use warehouse' command.
```

Comment: Check the query history in the Snowflake UI to see if warehouse is set when using the variable.

Comment: If you go into the Snowflake UI and set the context to the role you are using here, is the warehouse available to that role?

Comment: Thank you able to resolve. Provided Warehouses access to the Role.

Answer (score 1):

Provided Warehouses access to the Role.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).